# compress() function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some String fields in BQ that I would like to remove spaces from.  In SAS, there is a function compress().  Is there a comparable function in BQ?

```
WHERE firstname is not null
```

does not remove those records where there is a single space, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You may use the REGEXP_REPLACE function mentioned in the [Query Reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) to remove all spaces.

Use as:

> `REGEXP_REPLACE('orig_str', 'reg_exp', 'replace_str')`

for example:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(' remove all    spaces', ' ', '')
```

returns 'removeallspaces'.

Comment: Sorry for the late response to this question.  Thanks so much for your help!